# Importing XML file and then storing to pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I am fair new to Rails and stackoverflow. I have a fields like for example name, address with text-fields in form, when filling those two fields it need to be submitted in xml file which stored in public folder of rails app.

Example xml:

```
<name>abc</name>
<address>Madurai</address>
```

if there any solution please help me out. Don't be serious if any mistakes

Comment: in your controller `file = open('public/data.xml', 'w')
file.write params[:data]                                                                         file.close`

Comment: If possible will you explain me clearly...

Comment: parms[:data] means params[:name,:address]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= form_tag('/create_xml', :method=>'post') do %>
   <p>
       Name: <%= text_field_tag "name" %>
   </p>
   <p>
      Address: <%= text_field_tag "address" %>
   </p>
   <p>
       <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
   </p>
<% end %>
```

create_xml

```
def create_xml
    @data = params[:data]
    xml_file = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
       xml.streams {
           xml.content {
              xml.name { xml.text @data }
           }
       }
    end

    file = File.new('data.xml','w')
    file.puts xml_file.to_xml
    file.close
end
```

Comment: after saving to xml, can i conver it into overall pdf as:  

Name: ABC
Address: Madurai

Comment: but i need like these i have mutliple forms, Because am using more users pdf editable is not good thats the reason i am converting xml to pdf

Comment: I want to save the name and address in Xml tags 
<name>abc</name>
<address>Madurai</address>

Comment: On console try this if it work define in your controller `require 'builder'` `obj = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target => $stdout, :indent => 1)  then `obj.instruct!` will print `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` then `obj.name "abc"` will give you `<name>abc</name>` and  `obj.address "Madurai"` give `<address>Madurai</address>`

Comment: What you exactly A xml file with xm tags, which will be saved on you local drive or anything else

Comment: is it possible to store submitted fields into xfdf file

Comment: if you don't mind will you give sample code... My project is at end

Comment: `xfdf = Nguyen::Xfdf.new(FirstName: params[:firstname], LastName: params[:lastname])`
 `puts xfdf.to_xfdf`
 `xfdf.save_to('/home/sunil/file.xfdf')`
I have done like these, but it's not the right way to do. I want to pass all fields into array

Comment: Why don't you pass whole `params[:data]` to `Nguyen::Xfdf.new` it is expecting a Hash, and params is in hash format right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xfdf = Nguyen::Xfdf.new(FirstName: params[:name], Address: params[:address])
puts xfdf.to_xfdf
xfdf.save_to('/home/swetha/file.xfdf')
```

Specify the path `/home/swetha/` where you want to save the file

Comment: Yeah i did likewise but its the right way to do if have 20 params

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"uDX1vEdd7wu3CDy9rif7wp8jjCM1LsJwBtVHaXm1yDXYZtTi5Eq9B2hRz5QtQyeQ/2f3cwf4Zlxu76RfqXbY0w==",
 "firstname"=>"Welcome",
 "lastname"=>"Sreenu",
 "middlename"=>"Peruri",
 "fname"=>"Peruri",
 "lname"=>"Naga",
 "mname"=>"Raju",
 "mobile"=>"1123456789",
 "nation"=>"Indian",
 "commit"=>"Generate XML",
 "controller"=>"download",
 "action"=>"create_xml"}

Comment: It's working instead of passing each params, can we do pasing array wise?

Comment: For now you can try like this `params.except("utf8", "authenticity_token", "commit", "controller", "action")` or better way while passing from form pass as array of key and value pair

Comment: Hmm yeah and now the data in xfdf file need to fill in pdf fillable form . I am following the "Nguyen gem" 
  `pdftk = Nguyen::PdftkWrapper.new('/usr/bin/pdftk')`
 `pdftk.get_field_names '/home/swetha/output1.pdf''`
 `xfdf = Nguyen::Xfdf.new(FirstName: params[:firstname], LastName:  params[:lastname])`
`pdftk.fill_form '/home/swetha/output1.pdf', '/home/swetha/sample3.pdf' , xfdf`

Comment: it works but  the fields in not getting from xfdf file, its coming from             `xfdf = Nguyen::Xfdf.new(FirstName: params[:firstname], LastName: params[:lastname])`

Comment: Today i gonna ask you much more complex doubts @Sontya

Comment: Actually I have a pdf fillable form. Through ruby i want to read the fields and when user entered the details through my form. It needs to fill in the pdf fillable form. Example the pdf form is Government forms like passport application. 
is there any way to do these

Comment: wht do you mean by pdf fillable form, from where you want to read, plz @swetha reframe your question, sorry but I didn't understood, what you want exactly

Comment: Okay Pdf fillable form is like we fill  deatils in pdf. Example i have three fields in pdf 1)Name: textbox 2) Mobile: textbox 3) Gender: Radio buttons

II) I have a rails form which have three fields if i entered it will save automatically to pdf

Comment: share your email if possible

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to delete. u can delete i saved your email